# Master_slave in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing

How can we implement Master_slave configuration using RabbitMQ server.
I have read at many places and have experienced it myself that

"RabbitMQ Nodes under a Cluster can't really share same files except for the cookie file. Script itself makes sure that it creates folders and files names prefixed with "$NODE_ID$" while starting the broker so that all the files for that node will be created inside a single folder  ill  it. It basically creates two main folders inside folders does following thing: 
   a. db :  Creates Folder  named  "$NODE_ID$"-mnesia and creates all db files inside it.
   b. log : Creates files with name prefixed with "$NODE_ID$"
Even if we tweak the script for both nodes to point to same mnesia folder, 2nd instance of the broker will fail to start because of mnesia locking issue with following error :

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",
{{nocatch,{error,{cannot_start_application,mnesia,{killed,{mnesia_sup,start,[normal,[]]}}}}},[{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}} 
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump init terminating in do_boot ()".
```

All I wanted to know is if in a sitation in which there are 2 nodes 'master' and 'slave' in a cluster and if master is down for some time, then for that time how can slave can come in picture for recieving and sending messages on behalf of master. Since the sharing of database is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the guidelines for building a highly available cluster with DRDB and Pacemaker: http://www.rabbitmq.com/pacemaker.html

However, that's a bit difficult to set up, so you might prefer to wait for a few more weeks, as the next major release will include built in support for redundant queues for clusters. See more about that in the attachment here:

http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-June/013304.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.I had already seen this link, but I don't have much time to implement the whole pacemaker thingy. I thought there might be any another way. Anyways Thanks for your reply. ;)